# Adding a scrollview and get it to zoom

Tags: objective-c, uiview, scroll, zooming, scrollview

In my iphone app, you get a UIView with a background image and a "start button".
When you hit the start button, the start button will be hidden, and your background aswell.  You will see another image. You will also get a "back button".
You should be able to zoom the image and scroll around.
I want everything on the same UIView.

When you hit the back button, everything should get back to the first background image and the start button, and you should not be able to zoom or scroll.

How can I do this? And is it possible at all to hide a scroll view in order to just show a regular screen, in the same view?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ok, I know how to hide the scroll view now, but when the scroll view is shown, you can't scroll! I have made the scroll view bigger than the screen and put a label below the "original screen". How to get it to scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UIScrollView` to the main view in which you have the zoom/scrollable image. Simply remove it when the back button is pressed.

Comment: OK thanks! the main view, is that a special view or is it just the UIView where I have all the buttons and stuff?

Comment: Ok, I know how to hide the scroll view now, but when the scroll view is shown, you can't scroll! I have made the scroll view bigger than the screen and put a label below the "original screen". 
How to get it to scroll?